# If statement being ignored in update method when comparing float values

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The if statement is being ignored in the following code:

```
public class newscript : MonoBehaviour
    {

    private float oldPositionx;

    void Start()
    {
        oldPositionx = transform.position.x;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log("the oldPositionx is " + oldPositionx);
        Debug.Log("the current transform.position.x" + transform.position.x);
        if (transform.position.x != oldPositionx)
        {

            Debug.Log("if this is shown it's not working");
        }
    }
}
```

I have checked the console and the values being compared are equal, so I cannot figure out why the if statement is not working.

Comment: floating point numbers are error prone to strict equals/not equals tests.

Comment: Floats are inherently inprecise. Try not to pull your hair out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZRI1IfStY0